# How do I split and print values in xslt?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I want to create an xslt(version 2) where value can be split with delimeter ':' and print only first part of split and store the second part into a variable. The values have to be passed to a 'student' tag. Following are the values that are fetched from db
Adam:101
Brad:110
Chad:111

Expected output:
Adam
Brad
Chad

and values 101, 110 and 111 have to stored into a variable.

Please also provide a link where xslt2.0 tutorial is available in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use fn:tokenize() to achieve the output:

**Assume input:**

```
<student>Adam:101 Brad:110 Chad:111</student>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <students>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </students>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="student">
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ' ')">
          <student variable="{substring-after(., ':')}">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ':')"/>
          </student>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<students>
   <student variable="101">Adam</student>
   <student variable="110">Brad</student>
   <student variable="111">Chad</student>
</students>
```

Link: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcxx